# MySQL date: 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Tags: php, mysql

In my query:

```
       $cselect = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['cselect']);
       ---------------
       ---------------
       $sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO content
       (id, catID, title, abstract, body, status, published, date, description_meta,   keywords_meta)
        VALUES ('', '%s', '%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','', '' )", $cselect,$chead, $cabst,$ctext, $cp, $cradio,  'TIMESTAMP: Auto NOW()');
```

the output for date is:

```
0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

What is wrong in my query?

Comment: With NOW(): Fatal error: Call to undefined function NOW()

Comment: Well since there is no zero year that date is malformed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of specifying the Date in your query change your `date` column to a `Timestamp` type, and then set its default value to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

This way you wouldn't even need to bother with the `date` column in your queries, once MySQL will handle that for you, by inserting the actual date in UTC when it receives your insert query.

*Here goes the SQL query to change you date column:*

```
ALTER TABLE  `content ` CHANGE  `date`  `date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

`TIMESTAMP: Auto NOW()` is definitely not a correct value for a timestamp string and MySQL silently (unless you check warnings or enable strict mode) converts it to zero timestamp.

You should either use a function `NOW()` (without quotes around it) or rather `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` instead.

Comment: With NOW(): Fatal error: Call to undefined function NOW()
and CURRENT_TIMESTAMP output is 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Comment: NOW() is a MySQL function, not a PHP function. So keep it within the quotation marks.

Comment: Yes you need to quote it in PHP code, but not in SQL as original sprintf would do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `date('Y-m-d h:i:s')` instead of 'TIMESTAMP: Auto NOW()' for getting the current time.

Answer (score 1):

Any reason you're using sprintf() for this? You're not formatting any of the values, other than perhaps forcing things to be treated as strings. The following non-function version would be far more readable, using a [heredoc](http://php.net/heredoc)

```
$sql = <<<EOL
INSERT INTO content
    (id, catID, title, abstract, body, status, published, date, description_meta, keywords_meta)
VALUES
    ('', '$cselect', '$chead','$cabst','$ctext','$cp','$cradio', NOW(),'', '' );
EOL;
```

Note the `NOW()` call to fill in the date field. That returns the current date/time at the moment the query executes.

Please note that 'date' is a reserved word in MySQL and will cause syntax errors. You'll have to change the field name to something safe, and/or surround it with backticks (`) to 'escape' it.

As well, note that this way of building the query doesn't get around the fact that if any of this information is coming from untrusted sources you're wide open to SQL injection.